# Can't use automatic wrapper functions from AngelScript, C++ build fails

Tags: c++, game-engine, angelscript

I'm trying to compile [Amnesia: The Dark Descent](https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent/) videogame engine for an obscure processor architecture. I've managed to build and launch game successfully, but the game crashes while loading the first level. Log file implies, that [this function](https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent/blob/master/HPL2/core/sources/impl/LowLevelSystemSDL.cpp#L456C2-L456C2) from AngelScript bindings always fails. I've stumbled across [this bug](https://github.com/supertuxkart/stk-code/issues/2728) which seems like the same problem that I'm having. There, a solution is suggested, to use [automatic wrapper functions](https://angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_addon_autowrap.html). But when I replace (in the function mentioned above)

```
if(mpScriptEngine->RegisterGlobalFunction(asFuncDecl.c_str(),asFUNCTION(pFunc),asCALL_STDCALL)<0)
```

with

```
if(mpScriptEngine->RegisterGlobalFunction(asFuncDecl.c_str(),WRAP_FN(pFunc),asCALL_GENERIC)<0)
```

I get the following errors:

> the value of parameter "pFunc" (declared at line 462) cannot be used
> as a constant
> if(mpScriptEngine->RegisterGlobalFunction(asFuncDecl.c_str(),WRAP_FN(pFunc),asCALL_GENERIC)<0)

> no instance of function template "gw::Id::f [with T=void *]"
> matches the argument list
> object type is: gw::Id<void *>
> #define WRAP_FN(name)             (::gw::id(name).TMPL f< name >())

Can this be fixed without completely reworking the way the engine registers scripts?

It should be noted, that this engine must be built against AngelScript 2.19 (newer versions are confirmed to be working on the platform I'm using).

Comment: Do you know the calling convention?

Comment: Actually, I don't. But from the docs I assume WRAP_FN macro accepts functions, rather than function pointers... And I have no idea how to elegantly work around this.

Comment: I suppose it is a issue with stdcall/fastcall conventions or conversion from `void*` to `void(*)()` (is `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(void(*)()` for you?)

Comment: `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(void(*)()` is true